# Desactivar y activar un campo

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Tengo este formulario, lo que necesito es que el campo **Código Tarea** se mantenga disabled es decir discapacitado, pero cunado yo escoja el **Tipo** SysAid se habilite y cuando escoja algún otro vuelva y se ponga disabled, algún ejemplo JavaScript he intentado varias formas pero no logro conseguirlo este formulario se encuentra dentro de un modal no he usado mucho javaScript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código de formulario modal**

```
<!----Consulta para traer datos de los campos  SELECT---->
         <?php
$priorities =mysqli_query($con, "select * from priority");
 $kinds =mysqli_query($con, "select * from kind");
  $tareas =mysqli_query($con, "select * from tareas order by id desc");
               ?>


               <!-----Modal este modal se llama en ajax para mostrar su vista ---->    
<button id="line" type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg-new"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Nueva Tarea</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg-new" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
     <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Nueva Tarea</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <form action="sube.php" class="form-horizontal " method="post" id="add" name="add"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >  
          <div id="result"></div>



               <!---Compo para agregar el codigo de la tarea  INPUT---->
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
 <label  title="Codigo de la tarea">Código Tarea<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input style="border-radius: 5px;" type="text" required name="Codigo" class="form-control" placeholder="Código" disabled>
   </div>

                  <!---Compo para agregar el nombre de la tarea  INPUT---->     
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
 <label title="Nombre de la tarea" >Nombre Tarea<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input style="border-radius: 5px;" type="text" required name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre Tarea">
    </div>


<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label  title="Tipo de la tarea">Código</label>
 <select style="border-radius: 5px;" class="form-control" name="tareas" disabled >
  <?php foreach($tareas as $p):?>
   <option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>"><?php echo $p['id']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
     </select>
       </div>   


               <!---selecciona para traer datos de la base de datos "tabla kinds" SELECT----> 
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
 <label  title="Tipo de la tarea">Tipo</label>
  <select style="border-radius: 5px;" class="form-control" name="tipo" >
   <?php foreach($kinds as $p):?>
    <option value="<?php echo $p['name']; ?>"><?php echo $p['name']; ?></option>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>
        </div>


<!---selecciona para traer datos de la base de datos "tabla priorities" datos SELECT----> 
 <div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label title="Prioridad de la tarea">Prioridad</label>
    <select style="border-radius: 5px;" class="form-control" name="prioridad" >
     <?php foreach($priorities as $p):?>
      <option value="<?php echo $p['name']; ?>"><?php echo $p['name']; ?></option>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
          </div>


<!---boton para guardar el registro de la tarea BUTTON---->
 <div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <button id="save_data" type="submit" onClick="incrementar()" value="aumentar" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Registrar Tarea</button>
    </div> 

</form>
 </div>
  </div>
   </div>
    </div> <!-- /Modal -->
```

Answer (score 7):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Añades una función a tu select `tipo de tarea` con la propiedad `onchange();` de JavaScript

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label  title="Tipo de la tarea">Tipo</label>
    <select style="border-radius: 5px;" class="form-control" name="tipo" onchange="enableDisableCodigo();">
       <?php foreach($kinds as $p):?>
           <option value="<?php echo $p['name']; ?>"><?php echo $p['name']; ?></option>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Luego en esa función:

```
function enableDisableCodigo(){

    var codigo = document.getElementByName("Codigo"); 
    var tipo = document.getElementByName("tipo").value; // cogemos el valor tipo de tarea
    //Comprobamos el tipo de tarea para habilitar o no el campo Codigo
    if(tipo === 'SysAid')
    {
        codigo.disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        codigo.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

De esta manera conseguimos que al elegir el tipo de tarea sea *SysAid*, el campo *Código* se habilitara y cuando elijamos otro tipo de tarea el campo volverá a estar `disable`

Comment: Uy parce muchas gracias.

Answer (score 5):

Particularmente abogo por evitar en cuanto sea posible escribir funciones dentro de los elementos HTML, aunque es algo muy repandido, se considera una mala práctica<sup>1</sup>, porque crea un código HTML dependiente y a veces dificulta la reutilización de código o el mantenimiento.

Es mejor dar preferencia a la escucha de eventos, identificando el elemento por su id.

Imaginemos que el programa evoluciona, y hay elementos del HTML que deben invocar a `enableDisableCodigo` pero otros deben invocar a `enableDisableCodigoNew`. Si las funciones están en los HTML habrá que empezar a buscar allí para modificar la función que llama ese elemento. Si se implementa la escucha desde Javascript tan solo habría que actualizar el código ahí, sin tener que rebuscar en los HTML.

Propongo una solución usando esa técnica. Para cambiar el estado del otro `select` he puesto simplemente esto: `selCodes.disabled = !(mType == 'SysAid');`, dado que la parte de la derecha devuelve un booleano, no es necesario hacer la comparación con un `if`, el `select` se activará o no de acuerdo al resultado.

```js
/* Referecias a los select */
var selTypes = document.getElementById('selTipos');
var selCodes = document.getElementById('selCodigos');

/* Listener para los cambios del select tipos */
selTypes.addEventListener("change", enableDisableCodigo, false);

/* Función que se ejecuta cada vez que selTipos cambia*/
function enableDisableCodigo() {
  var mType = selTypes.value;
  /* Dado que la comparación devuelve un booleano podemos hacer esto*/
  selCodes.disabled = !(mType == 'SysAid' || mType == 'TFS');
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label title="Tipo de la tarea">Tipo</label>
  <select style="border-radius: 5px;" class="form-control" name="tipo" id="selTipos">
    <!--   
       <?php foreach($kinds as $p):?>
           <option value="<?php echo $p['name']; ?>"><?php echo $p['name']; ?></option>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
-->
    <option value="" selected>--Seleccione un tipo--</option>
    <option value="SysAid">SysAid</option>
    <option value="TFS">TFS</option>
    <option value="Tipo2">Tipo2</option>
    <option value="Tipo3">Tipo3</option>
    <option value="Tipo4">Tipo4</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Código</label>
  <select id="selCodigos" disabled>
    <option value="0" selected>--Seleccione Código--</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

---

1. Ver al respecto:

   - [Why Inline CSS And JavaScript Code Is Such A Bad Thing](https://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/)
   - [Why is using onClick() in HTML a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5871640/5587982)
   - [Why inline JavaScript is bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19002690/5587982)

Comment: Muchas gracias, con este funciona muy bien gracias  <3

Comment: oye estuve intentando validar no solo SysAid si no también TFS  selCodes.disabled = !(mType == 'SysAid'');    selCodes.disabled = !(mType == 'TFS''); validar los dos pero no tengo mucho conocimiento en javascript gracias

Comment: @EstebanGiraldo prueba de esta manera: `selCodes.disabled = !(mType == 'SysAid' && mType == 'TFS');`

Comment: no me funciona le he hecho de varias formas pero no

Comment: @EstebanGiraldo en ese caso sólo tienes que agregar la nueva condición a la comparación, usando el operador OR (`||`). Quedaría entonces así: **`selCodes.disabled = !(mType == 'SysAid' || mType == 'TFS');`** Revisa el fragmento de código actualizado con tu nuevo requerimiento.